# Pass cookie from Actor to Crawler

Tags: apify

I setup a crawler with URLs I want to crawl, actor is working, I tested with cookie/screenshot example. I just have problem with passing cookie from actor to crawl:

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const input = await Apify.getValue('INPUT');

    const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://xy.com/login');

    // Login
    await page.type('#form_user_login_email', input.username);
    await page.type('#form_user_login_password', input.password);
    await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelectorAll('.btn-full-width')[1].click(); });
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    // Get cookies
    const cookies = await page.cookies();

    // Use cookies in other tab or browser
    //const page2 = await browser.newPage();
    //await page2.setCookie(...cookies);
    // Get cookies after login

    const apifyClient = Apify.client;
    // call crawler with cookies
    const execution = await apifyClient.crawlers.startExecution({
    crawlerId: 'mhi',
    settings: {
      cookies: cookies
    }
    });

    console.log('Done.');

    console.log('Closing Puppeteer...');
    await browser.close();

});
```

I think cookie is not passed, because Crawler is not logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work. Maybe you can try to set `cookiesPersistence : 'OVER_CRAWLER_RUNS'` into settings. If you are not sure if cookies were passed, you can use API endpoint `https://api.apify.com/v1/user_id/crawlers/crawler_id?token=api_apify_token&executionId=execution_id` to check it.

But you don't need to pass cookies to crawler, you can crawl it directly in actor using Apify SDK. You need to just override goto function in PuppeteerCrawler, where you set cookies. Check to do for [doc for puppeterCrawler](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/puppeteercrawler).

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
    const input = await Apify.getValue('INPUT');

    const browser = await Apify.launchPuppeteer();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://xy.com/login');

    // Login
    await page.type('#form_user_login_email', input.username);
    await page.type('#form_user_login_password', input.password);
    await page.evaluate(() => { document.querySelectorAll('.btn-full-width')[1].click(); });
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    // Get cookies
    const cookies = await page.cookies();

    const crawler = new Apify.PuppeteerCrawler({
        // puppeteer crawler options
        gotoFunction: async ({ request, page }) => {
            await page.setCookie(cookies);
            return page.goto(request.url);
        }
    });

    await crawler.run();

    console.log('Done.');

    console.log('Closing Puppeteer...');
    await browser.close();
});
```